# how to tell user where is my shop?

Tags: android, android-maps

I would like to tell user where is nearest my shop from your current location.

How do I do it?

for example :

RED is user.

BLUE is radius.

GREEN is my shop.

BLACK is distance .

my shop is at 10 km the user ( but is not at 2 km the user.).

**Radius will be set by the user (with a seekbar).**

[image]

Comment: Well, you'll need to measure distance between 2 gps coordinates right?  You'll also need the user's position. I assume you know where your shop is already... So start there. Look up a formula for distance between gps coordinates.  If that distance is less than the value of the seek bar, do something. To get more help, you'll need to elaborate on your data sources, show what you've tried already, etc.

Comment: +1 for MSPaint handwriting

Comment: @William Morrison, yes.suppose I have several shops, After finding the nearest my shops by users, I would like to show my services from each shop to user. any ideas?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian I've posted a solution below describing exactly how I'd solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a web service which will read information about each of your shops from a database, and provide that information to client's in some standard format (xml, or json is typical.)  This information will include address, phone number, gps coordinates, available services, hours of operation, etc.

Next, get the user client's gps coordinates.  Then, query your web service from the user client.  Finally, measure the the distance between each shop's gps coordinate, and the client's gps coordinates with the [haversine formula.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Do what you need to with that information.  Display the nearest shop, display only shops within some distance- whatever.

If you too many shops (in the thousands at least) look into space partitioning data structures.  They're a favorite subject of mine, so maybe I'll be helping you in the future too!

Comment: You may find some advantage in doing the geographic calculation on the server rather than the client. Most server-side database systems these days have some form of geospatial support that makes calculating distances, etc., fast and easy.

Comment: @MattGibson thanks for elaborating, that's what I was getting at in my last paragraph there.  I see now I wasn't clear enough.  Of course the spatial partitioning won't be on the client side in this scenario. That's silly.